# Logitech Pro X stopped working after reboot

Tags: sound, usb, 22.04, pulseaudio, logitech

I'm having an issue with my Logitech, Inc. PRO X Wireless Gaming Headset in Ubuntu 22.04, and I'm hoping someone can help me out. Here are the key points of my problem:

I initially got my Logitech PRO X Wireless Gaming Headset to work by installing both solaar and headsetcontrol.

After installing these tools, everything seemed to be working perfectly. The headset was visible in solaar, and I could see it in the sound settings. The sound quality and microphone were flawless.

However, my problem arises after a reboot. Following the reboot, the headset disappears. solaar can no longer detect it, and it doesn't appear in the sound settings either. The only evidence of the headset's existence is when I run lsusb, which still shows the device as connected.

I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered a similar situation or has any insights on how to resolve this issue. It's frustrating to have it work initially and then stop functioning after a reboot.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!